# FormsCollection in Mvc Controller method - any other way of accessing?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a form which I want to post to ensure the page refreshes on posting the data (not the ajax way). The problem is really I only want to post the Id of the record and extract that in the controller method. I'm finding that the form is posting everything (I might not be able to resolve that since the same form is used for updating). But I'd like to be able to have the variable pop into the parameter of controller method rather than extracting from the FormCollection. I've tried the various parameters below, but all are being passed null.  Any idea what the problem is?

I have the following in my controller method:

```
public ActionResult Delete(FormCollection collection)
{
   var idToDelete =  collection["Current.CommissionStructureId"].ToInt32();
}

// tried the following but none of them bind
public ActionResult Delete(int? Current_CommissionStructureId, int? CommissionStructureId, int? Id, int? id)
{
    // none of the above are binding (set to null)
}
```

Comment: I don't know way to do that but what the problem to make separate form/link for deletion? As a simple solution you can add an hidden field to your form named CommissionStructureId.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use HttpPost only for deleting of records

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    <input type="hidden" name="CommissionStructureId" value="@item.CommissionStructureId" />
   <p>
   <input type="submit" value="Delete" />
   </p>
   <p>
   @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
   </p>
 }

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Delete(int CommissionStructureId)
{            
    CommissionStructure commissionStructure = db.CommissionStructures.Find(CommissionStructureId);
    db.CommissionStructures.Remove(commissionStructure);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When your form value is named `Current.CommissionStructureId` the default modelbinder will bind it only to a class parameter called `Current` with a property called `Id`.

So your options are

- Create a small class with one property `Id` and use it as your parameter type

or

- Write a custom modelbinder